# Cleaning ReSharper's TestResults files?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2008, resharper, temporary-files

I'm using ReSharper 4.5 to execute my MSTest unit tests in VS2008.  With each test run, it's creating files in this path:

```
testProjectFolder\bin\Debug\TestResults
```

How can I clean/delete those files from within Visual Studio?

If I can't delete them from within Visual Studio, when can I expect them to be removed?

I see Visual Studio's `Tools > Options > Test Tools > Test Execution > Test Results Management > Limit number of old Test Results to...`, and VS seems to honor it when you're using the stock VS test runner.  ReSharper doesn't seem to honor that setting, and I don't see a similar setting in ReSharper.  So, ReSharper's TestResults files just keep adding up on the disk?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The TestResults folder in itself is not an artifact of ReSharper, but rather of MSTest itself.

Here's a [blog post that describes one way of managing it](http://blogs.msdn.com/ploeh/archive/2006/07/13/CleaningAwayTheTestResultsFolder.aspx), and [here's the associated code snippet](http://blogs.msdn.com/ploeh/archive/2007/06/25/cleantestresultsXMLSnippet.aspx).

Comment: Doesn't work in VS 2010. The TestResults folder is not located where the code snippet expects it to be, but under bin/debug or bin/release.

Comment: In that case you just have to edit the code snippet to point to "bin\Debug\TestResults" instead of "..\TestResults" -- Or better yet, "bin\$(Configuration)\TestResults".

Answer (score 5):

I find the simplest way is to just add the following post-build step to my test project:

```
IF EXIST "$(TargetDir)TestResults" RD /S/Q "$(TargetDir)TestResults"
```